# Dropdown list apply more than edited row in appscript

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

First I am so sorry for my English Skill I have to use my poor English Skill to make this question.
I made a script to apply Depended Data Validation on `Column E` of `Orders` Sheet when new SKU added to `Column D`, like when I add 1 SKU to `D2`, `E2` will show dropdown list with all Supplier that SKU have (ex: SKU00124 have Amazon, Walmart, Chewy as supplier if I input SKU00124 to D2, E2 will show dropdown list with Amazon, Walmart, Chewy option for user choice, and SKU00122 have only Walmart, Amazon when I input SKU00122 to `D3`, `E3` will show Walmart, Amazon). SKU and Supplier Store at `Item_List` sheet with SKU at column B and supplier at Column E.
My issue is in `Orders` sheet `column D` where to store SKU, it get data from `Draft_Order` `column AA`, I am using a formula to get values of `AA` input to `D`.

```
={"SKU";ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:B="","",'Draft_Order'!AA2:AA))}
```

I see the script does not work correctly, I have to delete values in `column D` and when the formula gets values again the script runs. But it not set Data Validation to all range Ex: If SKU input from `D2:D20`, it not apply data validation to `E2:E20`, script just applies it row by row and only apply for 5 row (means only `E2:E7` applied data validation), if I want more I have to delete the rest of SKU.

I use onEdit(e) to catch cell edited on `column D`

Here is my example spreadsheet: [My Spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Iy76X-8EMLaiwLbuMRIPmMhK61J76iXOg-jRrT16qkQ/edit#gid=787168762)

Here is my script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get the active sheet
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  // Check if the active sheet is the "Order" sheet
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Order") {
    // Get the range that was edited
    var range = e.range;

    // Get the column of the edited cell
    var col = range.getColumn();

    // Check if the edited cell is in column D
    if (col == 4) {
      // Get the values in the edited range
      var values = range.getValues();

      // Loop through the values in the range
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
          // Check if the value is not empty
          if (values[i][j] != "") {
            // Get the SKU
            var sku = values[i][j];

            // Get the sources for the SKU using the getSources function
            var sources = getSources(sku);

            // Check if there are any sources for the SKU
            if (sources.length > 0) {
              // Calculate the row and column of the current cell
              var row = range.getRow() + i;
              var col = range.getColumn() + 1;

              // Get the cell in column E
              var cell = sheet.getRange(row, col);

              // Set the data validation for the cell using the sources list
              cell.setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(true).requireValueInList(sources).build());
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function getSources(sku) {
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get the "Item List sheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Item List");

  // Get the data in the sheet
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Create an array to store the sources
  var sources = [];

  // Loop through the data in the sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Check if the SKU in column B matches the input SKU
    if (data[i][1] == sku) {
      // Add the source in column E to the sources array
      sources.push(data[i][4]);
    }
  }

  // Return the sources array
  return sources;
}
```

I am trying to fix it by using a range define and apply validation for range length by using edit `values.length` but script applies data validation for a range more than SKU range.
Looks like if SKU values from `D2:D20`, the dropdown list will show on `E2:E35` when `D21:D35` is blank and does not have any SKU
and issue I got in first script still meets (only `E2:E7` is correct values of data validation, if I need more I have to delete it again.

Here is my try:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Order") {
    var range = e.range;
    var col = range.getColumn();
    if (col == 4) {
      var values = range.getValues();
      Logger.log("values.length: " + values.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
          if (values[i][j] != "") {
            var sku = values[i][j];
            var sources = getSources(sku);
            if (sources.length > 0) {
              var row = range.getRow() + i;
              var col = range.getColumn() + 1;
              var dataValidation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(true).requireValueInList(sources).build();
              // Apply data validation to the range of cells in column E
              var numRows = values.length;
              for (var k = 0; k < numRows; k++) {
                if (values[k][0] == "") {
                  numRows--;
                }
              }
              var validationRange = sheet.getRange(row, col, numRows, 1);
              validationRange.clearDataValidations().clearContent();
              validationRange.setDataValidation(dataValidation);
              Logger.log("numRows: " + numRows);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you see, I try to Logger.log numRow and value.lenght but after script run nothing show

please help me:

1/ script will run each time when I input SKU to AA column at `Draft_Orders` sheet

2/ Script will run when I input many SKU in 1 times like more than 100 SKU

3/ Script will apply to correct range (SKU have in `D2:D100` `E2:E100` have data validation not `E2:E250`

Comment: Please share a sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output.

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets/images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as plain text table to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are easier to copy/paste as well. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: I add my spreadsheet link on question: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Iy76X-8EMLaiwLbuMRIPmMhK61J76iXOg-jRrT16qkQ/edit#gid=787168762

Comment: Could some one help me, please

Comment: FWIW, the Data Validation in "Orders" Column E is a nightmare BUT... many businesses create their own product code on "Items List" for each item and link the suppliers SKU with that code. For example, you product code #599 (SKU#OSTERILITESTORAGE40GALX2, supplied by Walmart) and #600 (SKU#OSTERILITESTORAGE40GALX2, supplied by Amazon). On "Orders" insert a new column Column D with a lookup from the Items List", then the SKU, Supplier, etc are populated by using `arrayformula(vlookup)`.

Comment: @HOANGTRUNGLE if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75063548/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onEdit()` trigger works when the user edits the range. In this case you need to validate when edit has been done in the main sheet where you're getting the data from. You will need to validate whenever the user edits  column `AA` in sheet `Draft Order`. To give you an idea, check this script (make sure the ranges and sheet name matches with yours):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Draft Order") {
    var range = e.range;
    var col = range.getColumn();
    if (col == 27) {
      var values = range.getValues();
      Logger.log("values.length: " + values.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
          if (values[i][j] != "") {
            var sku = values[i][j];
            var sources = getSources(sku);
            if (sources.length > 0) {
              var row = range.getRow() + i;
              var col = range.getColumn() + 1;
              var dataValidation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(true).requireValueInList(sources).build();
              // Apply data validation to the range of cells in column E
              var numRows = values.length;
              for (var k = 0; k < numRows; k++) {
                if (values[k][0] == "") {
                  numRows--;
                }
              }
              var validationRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Orders").getRange(row, 5);
              validationRange.clearDataValidations().clearContent();
              validationRange.setDataValidation(dataValidation);
              Logger.log("numRows: " + numRows);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

References:
[`onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)